# gcloud cli shows less grantable roles than gcp console, for bigtable instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to programmatically assign roles to a member, for a bigtable instance.
I use the `list-grantable-roles` call on the `gcloud` cli to see what roles I can assing. It only returns below three roles, whereas the `gcp console` show me more roles than those three. What's is the reason for this?

Below is `gcloud list-grantable-roles` response

```
description: AutoML service agent can act as Cloud Storage admin and export BigQuery
  tables, which can be backed by Cloud Storage and Cloud Bigtable.
name: roles/automl.serviceAgent
title: AutoML Service Agent

description: Gives Cloud Data Fusion service account access to Service Networking,
  Cloud Dataproc, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Cloud Spanner, and Cloud Bigtable resources.
name: roles/datafusion.serviceAgent
title: Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent

description: Security reviewer role, with permissions to get any IAM policy.
name: roles/iam.securityReviewer
title: Security Reviewer
```

And here are the screenshots from the `gcp console` for a bigtable instance

[image: picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

[image: Picture 4]

---

Edit

Here I show the gcloud commands I use.
It is also interesting the `list-grantable-roles` command doesn't accept result from `--uri` call but when I remove the v2 and change bigtableadmin to bigadmin, it works.

[image: Terminal]

Comment: I don't know. I checked the request of the CLI and the UI, the result are the same. It's maybe harcoded. Don't know....

Comment: Could you provide the full command used to check the grantable roles?

Comment: I edited my question to add that command @Happy-Monad

Comment: What happens when you add --page-size=100 and --format=json to your command?

Comment: Still 3 result. @Nebulastic

Comment: Could it be that your own role acts as a filter on the result? Which means that as a project editor, for example, you cannot grant Bigtable owner permisisons?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the specific command that you're running but I suspect you may need to reference a Bigtable instance (or perhaps just a Project that has the Bigtable service enabled) to see the full enumeration of Bigtable-specific roles.

Regardless, if you know the role either from looking it up in the console or use the roles documentation ([link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/access-control#roles)), you should be able to specify this in the command in which you grant the permission to an identity, i.e.

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=.... \
--role=roles/bigtable.admin
```

#### 201209 Update

Can you please confirm the role of your default (current) account?

You should be able to:

```sh
CURRENT=$(gcloud config get-value account)

gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
--filter="bindings.members=user:${CURRENT}" \
--format="value(bindings.role)"
```

I created a service account with `Editor` permissions and it is able to enumerate all the roles.

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
ACCOUNT=[[YOUR-ACCOUNT]] # Perhaps `bigtable-tester`

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

# Create test service account, key and assign it project/viewer

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--role=roles/editor \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL}

# Authenticate as the service account

# Retain current account
CURRENT=$(gcloud config get-value account)

# Activate service account (this changes the default account)
gcloud auth activate-service-account ${EMAIL} \
--key-file=./${ACCOUNT}.json

# Revert to your original account
gcloud config set account/${CURRENT}

# Try the list using the service account
BIGTABLE="//bigtable.googleapis.com"
INSTANCE="testinstance" # Or whatever
RESOURCE="${BIGTABLE}/projects/${PROJECT}/instances/${INSTANCE}"

gcloud iam list-grantable-roles ${RESOURCE} \
--account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name)"
```

For me this returns:

```
roles/automl.serviceAgent
roles/bigtable.admin
roles/bigtable.reader
roles/bigtable.user
roles/bigtable.viewer
roles/datafusion.serviceAgent
roles/iam.securityAdmin
roles/iam.securityReviewer
```

And using the API Client Library for Node.JS:

```js
const {google} = require("googleapis");

const iam = google.iam({
  "version": "v1",
});

const BIGTABLE = "bigtable.googleapis.com";
const PROJECT= process.env.PROJECT;
const INSTANCE= process.env.INSTANCE;
const RESOURCE = `//${BIGTABLE}/projects/${PROJECT}/instances/${INSTANCE}`;

async function main() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  console.log(`Requesting: ${RESOURCE}`);
  const rqst = {
    fullResourceName: RESOURCE,
    auth: authClient
  };
  const resp = await iam.roles.queryGrantableRoles(rqst);
  const data = resp.data;

  data.roles.forEach(role => {console.log(role.name);});
  
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

See the APIs Explorer test and code samples:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/roles/queryGrantableRoles

Comment: I need to show the available roles via an api call to my users, rather than adding those roles for my own project.

I also edited my question to show the command you asked for. Thanks

Comment: Which language do you plan to use? I will try it this morning and, if it works, provide code to you

Comment: I'm using the gcp node.js sdk.